# sql query not printing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a dynamic query but for some odd reason its not running. Its not even printing. Please can anyone tell me why is the below dynamic query not printing.

```
DECLARE @CLIENTPK_NEW AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @CGNEEPK AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TYPE AS VARCHAR(10)

SET @CLIENTPK_NEW='6EF77AAA-1A7B-4D03-A448-D1088DED4134'
SET @CGNEEPK= NULL
SET @TYPE='Mag'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)       

SET @SQL = '    
SELECT       
PUBLISHER
FROM CLIENT_SHIPPINGREPORTDATA_FUNCTION('
  + @CLIENTPK_NEW + ' , ' 
  + @CGNEEPK + ' , ' 
  + @TYPE +' )' <=== This is the troubled line, but not sure what is error is.

PRINT  @SQL    <== **Why is this not priniting**
```

Many thanks

Comment: What type of SQL is this, SQL Server, MySQL, etc? Where are you running it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Noel said, it's because you're trying to concatenate a NULL into a VARCHAR - the end result will be NULL. You'd also need to enclose the other varchar values in single quotes to pass them in, which starts becoming messy/problematic.

Use parameterised TSQL instead. This will allow you to easily pass NULL into your function as well as helping protect against SQL injection.

```
DECLARE @CLIENTPK_NEW AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @CGNEEPK AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TYPE AS VARCHAR(10)

SET @CLIENTPK_NEW='6EF77AAA-1A7B-4D03-A448-D1088DED4134'
SET @CGNEEPK= NULL
SET @TYPE='Mag'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)       

SET @SQL = '    
SELECT       
PUBLISHER
FROM CLIENT_SHIPPINGREPORTDATA_FUNCTION(
  @CLIENTPK_NEW, @CGNEEPK, @TYPE)'

-- Then to execute it:
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, 
    N'@CLIENTPK_NEW VARCHAR(50), @CGNEEPK VARCHAR(50), @TYPE VARCHAR(10)', 
    @CLIENTPK_NEW, @CGNEEPK, @TYPE
```

Answer (score 9):

You are adding string values to a null value (`@CGNEEPK`) which results in `NULL`.  When you print `NULL`, you see nothing.  You need to use `ISNULL(@CGNEEPK, '')` instead.

Comment: I *think* @Amit is wanting to pass NULL into the function though

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
SET @CGNEEPK= ''
```

Answer (score 1):

If you concatenate a NULL to a string in SQL, the whole string will be NULL.  Change

```
SET @CGNEEPK= NULL
```

to

```
SET @CGNEEPK= ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a null-concatenation problem with @CGNEEPK as your setting it to NULL.
For all of your paramteres as ISNULL to them, or set @CGNEEPK = ''

```
SET @SQL = '     
SELECT        
PUBLISHER 
FROM CLIENT_SHIPPINGREPORTDATA_FUNCTION(' 
  + ISNULL(@CLIENTPK_NEW, '') + ' , '  
  + ISNULL(@CGNEEPK, '') + ' , '  
  + ISNULL(@TYPE, '') +' )' 

PRINT  @SQL    <== **Why is this not priniting**
```

Answer (score 0):

After the null problem (as answerd by a lot of others), you might look into the @TYPE variable. That is a string ('Mag'), so you need quotes around that value and the other strings:

```
SET @SQL = '    
SELECT       
PUBLISHER
FROM CLIENT_SHIPPINGREPORTDATA_FUNCTION('''
  + @CLIENTPK_NEW + ''' , ''' 
  + isnull(@CGNEEPK, '') + ''' , ''' 
  + @TYPE +''' )'
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, because it appears too stupid to be true:

```
PRINT '(1) This is ODD, ' + NULL +' very.'
PRINT '(2) This is ODD, ' + ISNULL(NULL,'') +' very.'
```

Displays only this:

```
(2) This is ODD  very.
```

The entire first line, beginning with (1), is omitted!